# inside deleteBaseBookings() function, this deleted the first row of id, when next time i delete another id, it will still takes prevoius id

Tags: reactjs

```
 setCheckIndex(){
        this.checkIndexStatus[id] = bVal
        let allCheckboxState = this.isAllChecked()
        if(!allCheckboxState.allChecked&&!allCheckboxState.noChecked){
            this.midCheckState = true
        }else{
            this.midCheckState = false
            this.isChecked = allCheckboxState.allChecked
        }
        this.setState({
            checkIndexStatus : this.checkIndexStatus
        })
    }



confirmDelete(bVal){


        console.log("hello world 1")
        if(bVal){
            this.deleteBaseBookings();
            console.log(bVal);
        }

deleteBaseBookings(){
```

...delete code here, after delete i am setting `checkIndexStatus=null` , but still i am getting previous id

```
         this.setState({
            checkIndexStatus :'null',
        })


}

<BookingComp bookingObj={item} setCheckIndex={self.setCheckIndex}
                                                        />
```

Comment: do something like: '' or null only. single quote is not needed

Comment: can you edit and post your constructor also?